# Why browsers do not send my explicit `Date` header?

Tags: javascript, http

Code example:

```
fetch('https://httpbin.org/get', {
    'headers': {
        'Date': (new Date()).toUTCString(),
    }
})
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Origin": "http://localhost:8000", 
    "Referer": "http://localhost:8000/", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.53"
  }, 
  "origin": "146.120.13.65", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Comment: Date is typically a *Response* header not a *Request* header, this is why you need JavaScript to push back local time if you need it.

Comment: @AlexK. from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html?shortFooter=true): `If you include a date or x-amz-date header, you must also include that header in the list of signed headers.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date` is listed in the [forbidden header names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) in the fetch spec.

> These are forbidden so the user agent remains in full control over them.
>
> - `Accept-Charset`
> - `Accept-Encoding`
> - `Access-Control-Request-Headers`
> - `Access-Control-Request-Method`
> - `Connection`
> - `Content-Length`
> - `Cookie`
> - `Cookie2`
> - **`Date`**
> - `DNT`
> - `Expect`
> - `Host`
> - `Keep-Alive`
> - `Origin`
> - `Referer`
> - `TE`
> - `Trailer`
> - `Transfer-Encoding`
> - `Upgrade`
> - `Via`